In chinese 命運, 安慰. In japanese 運命, 慰安. it seems chinese graphs are switched regularly
Why these differences are made. Thanks in advance. (This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.)
Edit.
Related https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121756/mom-and-dad-vs-dad-and-mom

Both pairs are used in both Chinese and Japanese, neither of the two pairs is strictly ascribed to just one language. Since each of those words is a coordinative compound, the order of the elements doesn't make much difference, just like it doesn't make any substantial difference when in English you say “mom and dad” or “dad and mom”.

This is not a regularity by any means. By the way, even within Chinese topolects/varieties there is some variation in this, for example Cantonese 喜歡 vs Mandarin 歡喜, Cantonese 韆鞦 vs Mandarin 鞦韆.

@jogloran Did you switch the Cantonese and Mandarin for that first one? Both 喜欢 and 欢喜 are used in Mandarin, though 欢喜 mostly in the adjectival sense ‘joyful, cheery’. The basic verb meaning ‘like, enjoy’ is definitely 喜欢 in Mandarin, not 欢喜.

I did switch them by mistake, thanks for pointing that out!
